# charging an auto battery for a gate opener?

Tags: battery-charging, generator

Commercial gate opening systems use solar recharging systems frequently. My location is inappropriate for solar but is right next to a small stream. What properties of a mini hydro generation would be necessary to keep a car battery charged through a dozen cycles per day. ie, wattage, amperage?

Comment: I could pull thousands of watts from a car battery - for a little while. We need to know more about how much energy a cycle of the gate requires, in terms of amperage. And I hate to say it, but unless you can get below the stream this may not be practical due to size, cost and efficiency.

Comment: Setting aside problems with practicality, we also need to know what the system needs, I.E. what kind of voltage, current, wattage, etc...

Answer (score 1):

You need to "float charge" the battery with a voltage of between 13.8 and 14.1V.

The output of mini hydro is likely to vary with the speed of the water.

You will need to either electronically regulate the generated output of the mini-hydro to 14V, or possibly (not a good idea) use a constant head of water to drive the mini hydro, such that it *always* outputs 14V.

You should also look at a caravan battery, rather than a car battery.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the gate opener is similar to a typical garage door opener -- 1/2 HP motor and similar operating speed. Back of envelope calculation: 400 Watts, 20 seconds operating time per cycle, 12 cycles per day =>
total power (energy) requirement per day = 400 x 20 x 12 = 96000 J.

Let's say the hydro generation operates 24 hours a day =>
power output requirement of generator = 96000 J / (24 x 60 x 60) sec = 1.1 Watt.

Above assumes close to 100% efficiency. Multiply the 1.1 Watt by some factor to cover inefficiency, etc. Perhaps use 1W x 4 = 4W as a starting point for your estimate.